# Continuity of a function on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

Given a function $F=F(x,p):\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and provided that

1. for each $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ $F(\cdot,p)$ is continuous.
2. exist $L>0$ such that $|F(x,p_1)-F(x,p_2)|\leq L|p_1-p_2|$ for all $x,p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

can I state that $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $(x_0, p_0)$ be arbitrary. Choose $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $|F(x, p_0) - F(x_0, p_0)| < \epsilon/2$ for $|x - x_0| < \delta_1$. Then
$$
$|F(x, p) - F(x_0, p_0)| \le |F(x, p) - F(x, p_0)| + |F(x, p_0) - F(x_0, p_0)|,
$$
where
$$
|F(x, p) - F(x, p_0)| \le L|p - p_0|.
$$
So if $|x - x_0| < \delta_1$ and $|p - p_0| < \delta_2$ where $\delta_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{2L}$ we have
$$
$|F(x, p) - F(x_0, p_0)| < \epsilon,
$$
proving continuity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are you using the$1$- product metric on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$, ie $d((x_0,p_0),(x,p))=|x_0-x|+|p_0-p|$? In this case, the $\delta$ in the definition above is $\delta=min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$? Right?

Comment: I am indeed using that metric. Note though that the topology induced by that metric is the same as that induced by Euclidean distance. This is due to the equivalence of all norms on finite-dimensional real vector spaces. For instance, with your $\delta$, the maximum norm would work as well.